# How to encode a filepath in a filename? (no collisions, crossplatform)

Tags: encoding, filenames, filepath

How can I encode a filepath in filename so the filename is valid and there are no collisions? In other words:

- The resulting filename does not contain special characters such as '\', ':' or '/'.
- Two different filepaths are never encoded into the same filename.

Example: filepath "C:\Program Files\My Program" -> filename "NGQqKY4pBaP7lPKQPD6Y..."

This example is only for illustration; there may be better (and simpler) ways to do this.

Problem background: This filepath encoding is used for a simple single-instance-check in Java: Two instances of the program can be run simultaneously if they are located in different directories, but not when they are located in the exact same directory.
I know there are other ways to ensure the single-instance property, but I find the filepath encoding to be the best in terms of cost-benefit-ratio in my particular situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the String of the path and encode just the specials, like:

```
% -> %%
\ -> %)
/ -> %(
: -> %;
```

No more special chars, but still useful and readable. However, since you just want to ensure uniqueness, a better (but not invertable solution) may be:

```
: -> ;
\ -> %
/ -> %
% -> %
```

I don't believe there will be a some%file and some/file in your filesystem, so this might work good enought for you.

Comment: But then C:\foo\bar.txt and C:\foo%)bar.txt will have equal names.

Comment: Then use my first conversion. I would go with the second, because NO ONE has a file foo%)bar.txt in his folders, AND and folder/file named foo/bar.txt.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The first conversion will be sufficient. :)